# finding max of random array

Tags: java, arrays, debugging, loops

I have been trying for a while to figure out how to find the max value of an array of random numbers. Here is the code i am debugging: as of now all I am getting is one value from the array but it isnt the max value.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(intOfMaxInRange(randomIntArray(10), 1,30));
    }
     public static int random(int low, int high){
        int x=(int)(Math.random()*high+low);
        return x;
    }
    public static int[] randomArray(int n){
        int[] a = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i<a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = randomInt (1,30);
    }
        return a;
    }
    public static int intOfMax( int[] array){
        int max=array[0];
        for(int i=1;i<array.length;i++){
            if (array[i] > max) {
        }
        }
        return max;

    }
```

Comment: You do NOTHING in the `if` statement. How it suppose to work? Assign `max=array[i]` inside the `if`.

Comment: Where's `intOfMaxInRange()` defined? Why is your indentation all wonky? Please put some effort into making your questions readable.

Answer (score 7):

You are on the right way, just add   `max = array[i];` into `intOfMax()` method:

```
 for(int i=1;i<array.length;i++)
 {
    if (array[i] > max)
       {
          max = array[i];
       }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you I cant believe I forgot that. Everyone on this site is so helpful. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (array[i] > max) {
    }
```

you forgot here these line:

```
 max = array[i];
```