# What is the best way to find the largest number in a random array?

Tags: java

An interviewer asked me how to find the largest number in a random array. I answered that loop the whole array to find the largest number but he said it would take too much time. I wonder if there is a better solution for it. Any suggestion?

Comment: If by "random array" he means "an array of randomly chosen values, with no other constraints (e.g. sorted)", then no, there is no faster way.

Comment: No other way. You need to see each number once, since there is no information to tell whether the unseen numbers are smaller.

Comment: Maybe it was a trick question, to get you to push back and tell him that there's no faster way.

Comment: It's either a trick question or the interviewer is not that bright.

Comment: StackOverflow agrees with you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13460478/finding-max-of-random-array

Comment: if you knew something about the distribution of the randomly chosen numbers then heuristically you could stop after seeing a large 'enough' number. But you would have no guarantee it would actually be the largest.

Comment: While you are looping through populating the array with random numbers, store the largest. :)

Comment: @TonyHopkinson That would be still `O(n)` :)

Answer (score 9):

Your interviewer probably wanted you to drill into details. When I interview someone, I would be looking for someone to ask these questions:

- How many numbers are there?
- What are the range of values in the array?
- Is the array sorted? (Yes, really)
- Where did the data come from?
- How often will this need to run?

I might answer, "They are ages between 15 and 99. And there are 100,000,000 of them." This would lead to an obvious optimization: if you see a 99, break your loop and return 99. That could save a lot of time. If the numbers are evenly distributed (you should ask!), this would take the average number of items you have to look at from 100,000,000 to under 100.

What I look for, is questions. I don't want someone jumping in and doing things they think are 'right' without knowing the details.

Even without silly constraints, a good candidate would try to figure out what type of system this is going to fit into. Obviously, finding the highest number in an array isn't going to be a one-time thing. If I need to repeatedly get the next highest number, again and again, sorting it first makes sense. If the array will be growing and I need to keep pulling out the highest then a heap makes sense.

You'll never know what your interviewer was thinking because you didn't drill down. That might have been all she was looking for, your questions. But even if she wasn't, even if she was just fumbling the question, by nailing down the details you would have demonstrated that you know what you're talking about.

Answer (score 2):

If the items in the array are random, the largest number could be at any position and you therefore need to read each item in the array to find the largest. Your  proposal is the most efficient method given the assumptions...

Comment: int[] random = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
Arrays.asList(random)  which will sort the list and then perform BINARY SEARCH on a sorted list ..... The reason I am asking is because i ma sure that you know this answer, but fir sime reason  held it back.

Comment: If the list is sorted, you don't need to do a binary search -- just look at the end (or beginning, if you sort descending order). But sorting it is going to take longer than just looking through it once. It _could_ be a viable answer, if the requirements are that other, similar operations will also happen ("find me the smallest number", "find me the median number", "find me the 473th smallest number"), such that it's worthwhile making the investment to sort.

Comment: I dont think Arrays.asList(array) sorts the array. Anyway sorting is O(n log n), but looping through the array once is O(n). So this is the fastest option.

Comment: I am not following you... Sorting is at least an O(n log n) operation so it can't be faster than a loop in O(n) unless the original array has some additional characteristics (e.g almost sorted).

Comment: @assylias Even if the original array is completely optimal for the sort algorithm, it's still not going to be faster than O(n). :)

Comment: Yes indeed (BTW +1 for your idea!)

Answer (score 2):

If the array is big, there *is* a faster way -- not faster in terms of CPU cycles, but faster in terms of wall clock. You could subdivide the array into sections (not by copying it, but by identifying start/end points) and then search each section in a separate thread. When all of the threads are done, find the largest number among the ones that each found. That way, you'll be able to solve the problem X times faster, where X is the number of cores on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

It most likely was a trick interviewers use to put you under pressure and "show nuts" by defending your answer.

There is no faster way to do this if you know nothing else about the array except that it is sorted. If the values are sorted or pre-organized in some way it might look different.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to look at every element in the array since it is unsorted.  I think when the interviewer said it would take long, you should have said, "yes, it could take long, but that's the only way".

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps he is testing your knowledge on algorithms.

Your method may take O(n), there are other sorting algorithms that can sort this random array into a ordered array, for example [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) makes O(nlogn) comparisons. It may have a bad worst case but this is rare.

In interviews I find it is always best to voice out your ideas, your assumptions your logic so that your interviewer is in the loop and gets an idea of how you think.